# Radeon Driver install help on Ubuntu

Tags: radeon, fglrx

I have a AMD/ATI  Radeon 7800 series VGA card.

I looked up ow to install the drivers under Ubuntu but could not work out how to do it.

I want to install the proprietary Fglrx driver.

The guide I followed was [this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI).

I used the: 2. Installation via the Ubuntu repositories

It said to get the `fglrx-installer`

I downloaded it (I wasn't even sure if was the correct one, I got `2:9.000-0ubuntu3` which stated it was the stable release.)

When I clicked on that it took me to this page:
[FGLRX driver download Ubutu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/fglrx-installer)

On this page it gave me 3 more download options. I choose the first one:
Download files from current release (`2:9.000-0ubuntu3`)

```
fglrx-installer_9.000.orig.tar.gz (106.7 MiB)
fglrx-installer_9.000-0ubuntu3.debian.tar.gz (42.2 KiB)
fglrx-installer_9.000-0ubuntu3.dsc (1.5 KiB)
```

I assume the first one was the correct one.

Now how do I install it?

The guide says to use the Hardware drivers Manager, but I can not find it.

So basically, I'm asking if I have the correct files?  Secondly where is the Hardware drivers manager, and once I find that how do I install the driver for the card?

Unless someone has another way of doing it that is easier?

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the file (right click then uncompress or unarchive) and then double click on the `.deb` file which will open the softwares manager.

Comment: Thanks, I can unzip, but there is no .deb file after i unpack it, i went right through all the sub folders I downloaded the fglrx-installer_9.000.orig.tar.gz (106.7 MiB)   as i think this is the correct driver? is that the correct driver for the 7800 radeon?